# How to use 3 background images for a resizable layout in CSS?

Tags: css

I'm working an a small website example and I want a resizable background for a div but can't seem to get the bottom background to work.

my CSS:

```
.content {
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(bodytop.png), url(body.png), url(bodybot.png);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-y, repeat;
}
```

How can I get this to work? The bodybot.png won't show up for me. Could i do this by creating a new div in my HTML? I want bodytop.png on the top, body.png resizing in the middle, and bodybot.png on the bottom. Thanks.

Comment: Hook us up with a fiddle www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: @VIDesignz    http://jsfiddle.net/XM8Nj/1/

Comment: Do you have a full link to the background images you are using? I only see blue in the fiddle...

Comment: I put links from imgur into the background-image line. They show up for me.

Comment: I got it, check the answer below, and the working fiddle. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you should do it....

Check the revised [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/QvXeU/)

**CSS**

```
 .container{
background: url(http://i.imgur.com/AFh3Y.png) bottom left repeat-x, url(http://i.imgur.com/kiCmk.png) top left no-repeat , url(http://i.imgur.com/3qKoZ.png) left repeat-y ;
width:960px; display:block;
}

.content {
padding: 10px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the `bodybot.png` is covered by `body.png`. you need to move `bodybot.png` to front.

The first image you put in the background-image is drawn last, and the last one is drawn first.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working. Can you give me an example where Bodytop .png will be om the top, body.png will be in the middle resizing itself, and bodybot.png will be at the bottom?